# How to calculate a Chi square in R programming?

Tags: r

This is my data frame called mydata.

```
                   Denomination     
Attendance    Protestant Catholic Jewish
Regular          182      213    203
Irregular        154      138    110
```

I want to calculate the hypothesis for this through a chi square test. So i set my hypothesis like this:

> H0: There is no relation between denomination and attendance
>
> H1: There is a relation between denomination and attendance.

I've tried by calculating actual value and expected value and compare them to calculate chi square. But didn't get the output.

The codes I've tried:

```
> rowSums(mydata,na.rm = FALSE,dims = 1L)
> colSums(mydata,na.rm = FALSE,dims = 1L)
> sum(mydata)
> e = rowSums(mydata) * colSums(mydata)/ 1000
> chisq.test(mydata) = sum((mydata-e)^2 / e)
```

But I didn't get the result. Please suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things to note here:

1. `chisq.test` can only have numeric columns (or integer). The way you have displayed the data, it seems as though `Attendance` is its own column as opposed to the `rowname`.
2. You don't need to calculate `rowSums` or `colSums` to use the test.

Here is the code I ran:

```
dfs <- data.frame(Attendance = c("Regular", "Irregular"), Protestant = c(182, 154), Catholic = c(213, 138), Jewish = c(203,110))
rownames(dfs) <- dfs[,1]
dfs$Attendance <- NULL
chisq.test(dfs)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  dfs
X-squared = 7.8782, df = 2, p-value = 0.01947
```

Comment: @Alex Did this work for you? if so could you checkmark it so I know it is closed. Thanks

Comment: Sorry i was out from the town. Thank you so much. It was really helpful..